# Spring WebFlux - how to return a different type than Mono source?

Tags: spring, rx-java, spring-webflux

Doing my first steps with Spring Reactor, I'm struggling how the RestController can return a different bean the input parameter. I've the following method:

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<Site> create( @RequestBody Publisher<Site> site )
{
    return Mono.
            from( site ).
            doOnNext( repository::save);
}
```

Assuming repository::save returns a boolean to indicate success or failure, how can one grab this returned value and use it to return some custom DTO in response? So final method will looks something like:

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<SomeResponse> create( @RequestBody Publisher<Site> site )
{
    return Mono.
            from( site ).
            doOnNext( repository::save)
            .someCodeThatGetTheReturnedValueAndReturnsSomeResponse;
}
```

Comment: Mono::map method is often used for transformations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Mono::map](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [Mono:flatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) for transformations.

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<SomeResponse> create( @RequestBody Publisher<Site> site )
{
    return Mono.
            from( site )
            .map(repository::save)
            .map(booleanVar -> createSomeResponseFromBoolean(booleanVar));
}
```

Comment: above +1 but if repository.save returns Mono<Void> use .then()